# Clear a specific select in react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-bootstrap

I need to clear the second select if it already has a selected value, in case the first one selects `B`.

When cleaning it requires that the value be `removed`, `disabled` and that it has the `Select...` option by default.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form, Col, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    to: "",
    from: "",
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  return (
    <Form>
      <Form.Row>
        <Form.Group as={Col} md="auto">
          <Form.Label>to</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            required
            name="to"
            as="select"
            placeholder="to"
            onChange={handleChange}
          >
            <option hidden value="" selected>
              Select...
            </option>
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
          </Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group as={Col} md="auto">
          <Form.Label>from</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            required
            name="from"
            as="select"
            placeholder="from"
            onChange={handleChange}
          >
            <option hidden value="" selected>
              Select...
            </option>
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
          </Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>
        <Button variant="primary">Ok</Button>
      </Form.Row>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default App;
```

How can I modify the code above to do what I commented? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you have here is `cascading` issue your second select depends on the first select. In your handle change you can do this

```
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    if(name === 'to' && data.from){
      setData((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        [name]: value,
        from: ''
      }));
    } else {
      setData((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        [name]: value,
      }));
    }
  };
```

We are checking whether the value we are changing is the first select and also if the second select already has a value . If yes then we are clearing the value in the second select.

Also since you are using the state to preserve the form values , you need to add the `value` prop to your component to make it as [Controlled Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) .

```
 <Form.Control
     required
     name="to"
     as="select"
     placeholder="to"
     value={data.to} // add this prop
     onChange={handleChange}
  >
    <option hidden value="">
       Select...
    </option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
 </Form.Control>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will be implementing it and I will tell you